# library that provides date time angular

Tags: angular, date, time, popup, shared-libraries

I am looking for a library that could provide me with this kind of date time
[popup date time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhnuR.png)

I must be able to choose the month, the year, the day and the hour then by clicking outside the popup I must be able to select them without a confirmation button (I don't know if I'm clear)

Comment: StackOverflow isn't for generic questions so your question will probably be locked. However, you're probably looking for [Angular Material, which includes a datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview).

Comment: You can use NG-ZORRO Datepicker https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r38q3l